# How can i use react-sortable-tree on react version 18?

Tags: reactjs, react-sortable-tree

I want to use react-sortable-tree on my project.

And this is the tree library link : https://npm.runkit.com/%40nosferatu500%2Freact-sortable-tree

my project was made by cra(create react app) and
this my code

```
import React, { Component, useRef, useState } from "react";
import { Menu } from "../../@types/menu/menu";

import SortableTree from "@nosferatu500/react-sortable-tree";
import "@nosferatu500/react-sortable-tree/style.css"; // This only needs to be imported once in your app

interface Props {
  menus: Menu[];
  setMenus: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<Menu[]>>;
}

const Tree = ({ menus, setMenus }: Props) => {
  const [treeData, setTreeData] = useState([
    { title: "Chicken", children: [{ title: "Egg" }] },
    { title: "Fish", children: [{ title: "fingerline" }] },
  ]);
  return (
    <div style={{ height: 400 }}>
      <SortableTree
        treeData={treeData}
        onChange={(treeData) => setTreeData(treeData)}
      />
    </div>
  );
};

export default Tree;
```

and this is my error code

```
./node_modules/@nosferatu500/react-sortable-tree/esm/index.js 1123:80
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1123:80)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
|         }).map(function (_, index) {
|           return /* @__PURE__ */jsx("div", {
>             className: classnames("rst__loadingCirclePoint", rowDirectionClass ?? "")
|           }, index);
|         })
```

plz help me

I use my code with class components but it didnt work

Comment: Can't reproduce, see https://codesandbox.io/s/so-34604296-s843l2?file=/src/App.js